# Using commit() inside OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener()

Tags: android, performance, persistence, sharedpreferences

I am using an OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener():

```
listener=new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,
            String key) {
        if(key.equals("TIME"))
        {
            Log.v("Tagger","Value has changed");
            long L=-2;
            if(sharedPreferences.contains("TIME"))
            {
                L=sharedPreferences.getLong("TIME", 0);
                long  HH=(L/1000)/3600; 
                long MM=((L/1000)/60)%60;
                long SS=(L/1000)%60;
                MILLIS-=1000;
                mainHH.setText(Long.toString(HH));
                mainMM.setText(Long.toString(MM));
                mainSS.setText(Long.toString(SS));
            }
            if(L<=0)
            {
                Editor edit=sharedPreferences.edit();
                edit.remove("TIME");
                edit.commit();

                Log.v("VALUE",Long.toString(454L));
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TimerAlarmReceiver.class);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
                TimerAlarmReceiver.alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                TimerAlarmReceiver.alarmMgr.cancel(pendingIntent);
                start.setText("Start the Test?");
                TimerOn=false;

                edit.putBoolean("TimerOn", TimerOn);
                edit.commit();          
            }
        }
    }
};
sharedPreferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener);
```

It is logical to not put the call to `commit` inside the listener as it will become recursive and cause a StackOverflow. But what I don't understand is why this code works fine on higher versions of android (tested on >4.X). But when I use it on android 2.3, it causes the expected error.

How do I:

1. Get it running on older versions of android 
                        OR
2. Add an exception not to fire the listener when I call the commit() inside it?

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the recursion with the infinite loop problem always by using a **base case**. The function of **base case** is to stop your recursion when your app reaches a specific pre-defined state.

In you case you can use one of the following solutions:

1)Unregister the `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` when your skipping condition happens using

```
sharedPreferences.unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener);
```

2)Create global a boolean `flag` into your `class` and check it before executing your logic within the `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` and set it with `false` when you reach your **base case**

```
private boolean changesFlag = true;
```